# How to determine whether property should be placed in view or in the model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I guess I'm a little confused as to whether properties like display range should be placed in the model (that gets inherited as a datacontext so that subcontrols can bind to it easily)or whether I should have properties be placed in the graphviewer class, and then let the components that need access to it have their own properties that they bind to the ancestor instead. Is it cleaner to bind to an ancestor control or just to bind off the model? I feel like the latter is cleaner, but then display range is pretty clearly a property of the view.

For example. I have a property AxisdivisionUnit that is needed in a scrollviewer, as well as used by a few thumbs to recalculate position on graph updates. The scrollviewer only appears when a treeview in the top level control (graphviewer) is populated. So I could either put the property axisdivisionunit on the graphviewer and bind the property to properties in the scrollviewer and thumb. Or I could have the thumb and scrollviewer bind to properties in the model (viewmodel if i were better at separating the UI out entirely.

Comment: If a property can't be described without talking about UI, it's a good indication it belongs on the view. If a property doesn't describe what your model is, it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Ah I see your new question, I'm going to suggest you re-edit this question and delete the edit: and start a new question so that I and others may be able to answer it.. tag with C# WPF and dont' forget MVVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me  see if I can help..

First off, since you are discussing mainly the presentation of what things look like on your UI, then I do not think that the property should be in your model at all. The real question is whether it belongs in your View or ViewModel.

AxisDivisionUnit, sounds like it is only part of how the graph looks. I'm thinking that it would make more sense for that to be in the view only. If you had some properties describing the limits of your graph that were tied to business logic, then something like that may be better off in the ViewModel since you could possibly want to test that code and if you were to replace the UI you'd still want to enforce those exact same limitations.

I guess ask yourself, "If I were to replace this graph with a totally different graph and UI to display the same data, would I have to enforce this same logic?" If the answer is no, that it is just how you want to display it for this case... then it belongs in the View and you can bind a Control's property to another control's property or use triggers, behaviors, etc. to implement it in the View.

Comment: ok thanks. I guess the real issue is that I just find that the code would look cleaner if I could just inherit the datacontext rather than referencing an actual component because all the binding statements wouldn't be based off an elementname or relative source. In addition, I find that the top level view class already has a lot of properties, while my view/ view model does not. But in the end, the properties do have more to do with the view than the model.

Comment: can you look at another small question?